# loosening frozen coax connectors

Tags: connectors

I have purchased some 2M yagis which were removed from service. the coax connectors have BNC adaptors screwed into them which have become frozen in place with weather exposure. Is there a way to unscrew them without destroying the entire connector?

Comment: I'll assume you mean stuck where you say frozen, and specifically stuck due to corrosion? Also, what kind of coax connectors are you referring to? N-Type? SMA? A BNC variant? (BNC itself *is* a coax connector) if this is domestic installation, f-type? 7/16 DIN? There are **very** many different coax connectors! I think adding a photo to your question might help a lot.

Comment: By the way, I just realized you're Niels Nielsen with the experience in amplifiers: You might be interested in [this](https://tkb-schmidt.de/MAE.pdf) freshly updated document, specifically sec. 5.7.1. Corroded connectors' oxide/metal interfaces are functionally nonlinear elements, and hence potentially generate all the nice intermodulation products that you try to get rid of in your power amplifier :D

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for that reference! I know people who have used that trick to make distortion units for electric guitar> -NN

Comment: yep, now imagine you're building a cellular base station with an accidentally added effects pedal at the output, and at the output of that guitar effect pedal you have to still output more than 1000 equidistant tones, spaced 15 kHz apart somewhere around 2 GHz, each carrying separate information that's not supposed to bleed into each other :D That's why cellular wireless people are kind of nervous around oxidized connectors.

Comment: I'd like to second @MarcusMüller's request for a photo. That will help identify what sort of mechanical force and/or strategic disassembly can be used, and possibly if they're unsalvageable.

Comment: I was wondering if placing the connectors in a bath of baking soda and salt with aluminum foil (contacting all silver) would remove silver oxide like they do for silverware? In my case, the thought is to clean up some old unused, but oxidized connectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are adapters frozen on the end of the cable, it's probably best to just cut the whole thing off and reterminate the cable with a new end.

The reasoning is:

- Strenuous mechanical attempts to separate them are likely to damage the connector anyway, at which point you will have to replace it...
- If it has been weathered, likely it is corroded, so even if you succeed in separating them, you will likely find replacing it is necessary anyway.
- It might be less work to cut it off and replace it than separate it.

So I'd probably make a faint attempt at separation, but if it started becoming an effort, just cut it off.  And while you are at it, examine the raw coax end to make sure the coax isn't also damaged from water intrusion...

Answer (score 2):

As @user10489 said most likely the corrosion will have damaged the connector enough to require replacement, but it is still worth making an attempt.

I do recommend getting a pair of soft jaw pliers, also known as cannon plug pliers. They have smooth jaws with fairly rigid rubber inserts to grip the connector. I have seen people try to put covers over the jaws of slip joint pliers, but that does not work as well.

[currently on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08818RC7C)

Try switching between tightening and loosening the connection. The goal to break the corrosion free. Often you will have more luck tightening than loosing the connector.

There penetrant oils you can spray on the connector, but I have not had much luck with them on connectors. They seem to work better on bolts and nuts.

You could try applying heat, but enough heat to break the connector free will probably damage it.

If the soft jaw pliers do not work, I would recommend simply cutting the connector off.

Comment: I think the line between "faint attempt" and "too much effort to remove" is a very personal one, partly depending on experience of past success and tools available and how willing you are to hurt the connector (or yourself) trying.  This is a good list of things to try for those willing to go that far.